# Bitbake rpi-basic-image Error ninja-build

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, bitbake, ninja, openembedded

I'm learning Yocto project. Started creating an image for Raspberry Pi 4.
I ran `bitbake rpi-basic-image` and got an error:

```
fatal: repository '/PATH/yocto/rpi64-build/downloads/git2/github.com.ninja-build.ninja.git/' does not exist
```

but when i run `bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel` everything dowloads and works fine.

I didn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more of the build log?   It looks like a previous download of ninja has been manually previously deleted, try deleting `*ninja-build*` in `downloads/` and `downloads/git/`.

Comment: DEBUG: Executing python function do_unpack
DEBUG: Executing python function base_do_unpack
ERROR: Unpack failure for URL: 'git://github.com/ninja-build/ninja.git;branch=release;protocol=https'. No up to date source found: clone directory not available or not up to date: /home/andrew/projects/embedded_linux/yocto/rpi64-build/downloads/git2/github.com.ninja-build.ninja.git; shallow clone not enabled
DEBUG: Python function base_do_unpack finished
DEBUG: Python function do_unpack finished

Comment: Delete the files I suggested and try again?

Answer (score 0):

[files tree screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWU3h.png)

[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPPM1.png)

Comment: Welcome Andrew :) Please share any relevant code in our Answer. Not all users will click on links and therefore won't be able to help reproduce, and solve, your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).